# Counting the number of unique words

Tags: python, unique, words

I want to count unique words in a text, but I want to make sure that words followed by special characters aren't treated differently, and that the evaluation is case-insensitive.

**Take this example**

```
text = "There is one handsome boy. The boy has now grown up. He is no longer a boy now." 
print len(set(w.lower() for w in text.split()))
```

The result would be 16, but I expect it to return 14. The problem is that 'boy.' and 'boy' are evaluated differently, because of the punctuation.

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual number would be 14. Since you have the word `boy` three times, and the words `is` and `now` twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
print len(re.findall('\w+', text))
```

Using a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) makes this very simple. All you need to keep in mind is to make sure that all the characters are in [lowercase](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower), and finally combine the result using [set](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to ensure that there are no duplicate items.

```
print len(set(re.findall('\w+', text.lower())))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `regex` here:

```
In [65]: text = "There is one handsome boy. The boy has now grown up. He is no longer a boy now."

In [66]: import re

In [68]: set(m.group(0).lower() for m in re.finditer(r"\w+",text))

Out[68]: 
set(['grown',
     'boy',
     'he',
     'now',
     'longer',
     'no',
     'is',
     'there',
     'up',
     'one',
     'a',
     'the',
     'has',
     'handsome'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have the right idea of using the Python built-in set type.
I think that it can be done if you first remove the '.' by doing a replace:

```
text = "There is one handsome boy. The boy has now grown up. He is no longer a boy now."
punc_char= ",.?!'"
for letter in text:
    if letter == '"' or letter in punc_char:
        text= text.replace(letter, '')
text= set(text.split())
len(text)
```

that should work for you. And if you need any of the other signs or punctuation points you can easily
add them into punc_char and they will be filtered out.

Abraham J.

Comment: What if the string has a `,`, `'` , `?` , `!` or any other character? will he need to hard-code checks for those as well? The text in the questions was obviously just an example.

Comment: he can use something like: punc_char= '.,!?' and then use that in place of the "hard-code" '.' so he would say something like          if letter in punc_char:

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get a list of words. You can use a regex as eandersson suggested:

```
import re
words = re.findall('\w+', text)
```

Now, you want to get the number of unique entries. There are a couple of ways to do this. One way would be iterate through the **words** list and use a dictionary to keep track of the number of times you have seen a word:

```
cwords = {}
for word in words:
     try:
         cwords[word] += 1
     except KeyError:
         cwords[word] = 1
```

Now, finally, you can get the number of unique words by

```
len(cwords)
```

Comment: Note that you can use `collections.defaultdict(int)` of `collections.Counter()` instead of the try/except with a dict. In fact, in this case, seeing he just wants the number of unique words, all you need is a `set()`.